# When navigating out of an application, what is still running, what is not running

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8

On a `Windows Phone 8` app, if I navigate to another application, i.e. in the music player, is there some threads that are still alive in my application? What is the name of this distinction between what is running and not when I'm navigating between pages, or when I'm navigating out.

From an `MSDN` perspective, what should I search to understand better about running threads and stopped threads when navigating out, or how pages are re-instantiated when navigating back and forth?

I'm developing an app where `background threads`, as well as disposing certain resources, is very, very important, and I noticed that navigation is the main concern for me when developing bigger applications on `Windows Phone`. I'm starting to maintain several infos about navigation behaviors, because in some scenarios (ex: `CameraCaptureDevice`), resources are hard to manage, so the app only remains stable when forcing some path between pages. If I navigate back to some specific page, a member of a resource make an unhandled exception, so I go behind the page then navigate on it, it can be achieved in 1-2 seconds and it's a life saver for the app.

So, I'd like to learn some basis about how the navigation works. I guess I should first search in `Silverlight` stuff, as it's probably similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit your application, *everything* is frozen. Furthermore, the application can be terminated while frozen to free up resources so you cannot guarantee you'll ever be unfrozen.

Certain tasks (like Audio, Periodic, and Resource Intensive Agents) run in the background, but these are separate *processes* and are launched by the operating system.

All the information you want is on [Launching, resuming, and multitasking for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and it's sub-pages on MSDN.